# Shade multiple versions of a direct dependency in a maven project

Tags: java, dependency-management, maven-shade-plugin, build-dependencies

We have a maven project, `A`, which depends on `B`. We are planning to use multiple (three) versions of `B` so that `A` could work on those multiple versions directly and produce a single uber-jar which contains different artifacts compiled using the different versions of `B`.

We were thinking of relocating/shading the different versions of `B`, and call them as "previous", "current" and "next" after relocation. However, we are not really sure how we can include the three versions altogether. Is there a way to define the pattern within the shade plugin such that we can include those dependencies that way?

Comment: Is `B` being included three times in order to support three different versions based on other applications? My knee-jerk approach here would be to have three modules within the project, which are parented to your primary maven project. These three modules could then depend individually on each version of `B`, implementing specific code to that version of `B`, and then having the appropriate module loaded at runtime (where they would share common methods between the three versions, such that your primary code is version-agnostic)

Comment: Kind of true, yes. We add `B`'s version to the metadata of the artifact created by A. That way other applications that use the artifact know it was compiled using a specific version of `B`. The aim is to allow flexibility of supporting up to three different versions in the artifact for the downstream applications. We were planning for a similar solution, but we didn't want to replicate the necessary querying done by `A` multiple times. We just want to compile the artifact (multiple times) using different versions of `B` and fetch the data only once

Comment: "necessary querying" meaning something specific to your application in `A`? Basically, the idea behind this is the three modules `A1/A2/A3` are essentially a "Wrapper" of the functionality provided by the library `B`. Then the primary `A` will call upon your module's methods, which in turn call the appropriate ones for the specific version of `B`. You should be able to do this in a way such that `A1...3` are providing only the functionality aspect, while keeping the logic of how the functionality is used within `A`.